# Value of type String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling with an error that tells me that it cannot convert a String value to JSONObject. I'm trying to pass a CSRFToken as a parameter to my JSONObjectRequest. I have no clue if this is the right way to even go about it.

I'm getting the error message: `org.json.JSONException: Value inz9J9w0N5qASdJO8soWFBZ4UrEpdnjnpmxvFbJ2 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Relevant code is below.

```java
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("_token", ((TestApplication) getApplication()).getCSRFToken());

JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        Log.i("response", response.toString());
        alertDialog.setMessage(response.toString());
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(error.getMessage());
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Does anyone know what I may have done wrong and how to rectify the issue?

Comment: Does .getCSRFToken() return exactly "inz9J9w0N5qASdJO8soWFBZ4UrEpdnjnpmxvFbJ2" or are there additional characters like quotes or curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be valid.

```
{
    "_token": "inz9J9w0N5qASdJO8soWFBZ4UrEpdnjnpmxvFbJ2"
}
```

Can you try

```
String tokenString = (String) ((TestApplication) getApplication()).getCSRFToken();
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("_token", tokenString);

JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
// ...
}
```

Comment: I had also tried that method instead of using HashMap. I've been playing around with it for hours, it doesn't make any sense. Is there a way I can find out more information about the error? VolleyError must have something.

Comment: I found out that (for whatever reason) my server is returning the token and the error is occurring in `parseNetworkResponse`.

Comment: So it seems not a problem of json conversion, but when your server responds. Can you check the response from your server to make sure it returns correct data format.

Comment: It does return a JSON object when I make post requests with Axios in JavaScript so I'm trying to figure out what may be causing it to return the same token that I'm sending it instead of going ahead with validation.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. `JsonObjectRequest` doesn't send any accept headers. After adding an accept header I was able to get the response I was after.

Final code:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // ...
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        //alertDialog.setMessage(error.toString());
        alertDialog.setMessage(new String(error.networkResponse.data));
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("X-CSRF-TOKEN", ((TestApplication) getApplication()).getCSRFToken());
        params.put("Accept", "application/json");
        return params;
    }
};

queue.add(stringRequest);
```